# How to get steam gameserver player count using steam API?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

could someone help me to find out how I can get a server player count using steam API?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this with Steamworks API would be via obtaining `gameserveritem_t` item, which contains player count `m_nPlayers` among other useful info about a server. It is returned by `GetServerDetails` method (see https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamMatchmakingServers) which you can call during callback from server list query, for example `RequestInternetServerList`.

One thing to mention is that in order for callbacks to work the `SteamAPI_RunCallbacks()` should be called frequently.